Normal sheaf of the image of an unramified morphism
Let $X, Y$ be smooth projective complex irreducible varieties with an unramified finite morphism $f: X\to Y$. Let $Z$ be the image of $f$ and assume that the restriction map $g:X\to Z$ is a birational morphism, and for any $z\in Z$, either $f^{-1}(z)\cong \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbf{C})$ or $f^{-1}(z)\cong \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbf{C}) \cup \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbf{C})$. In particular, $g$ is the normalization map of $Z$.
Question: Is it true that $g_*N_{X/Y}\cong N_{Z/Y}$?

The normal bundle is usually defined only for subvarieties. So, what do you mean by $N_{X/Y}$?

@Sasha It can be defined as the cokernel of $T_X\hookrightarrow f^*T_Y$, or (equivalently) as the $H^{-1}$ of the cotangent complex of $f$.
